# gradle not syncing when adding firebase to android studio

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-manifest

So I'm trying to add the Firebase SDK to my Android Studio app as per the instructions from the Firebase website (see picture).

Adding the line `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'` to the project level gradle works fine. I can sync the gradle files.

However, adding the line `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the app level gradle file breaks my app. 
I get the following error:

ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-21:19 to override.

So i go to do the suggestion. I add `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` to >application< element in AndroidManifest.xml file. This then gives me a *Namespace "tools" not bound* error. I press Alt+Enter to fix which adds `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to the top of my file.

Try sync again. Now i get a similar error: *ERROR: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs*. And this is where I'm lost. I'm not sure what to search in Google. a search for this specific error brings up a lot of answers that aren't related to my problem. This territory is completely new to me.

P.S. On top of all that, the line `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`inside my build.grade(app level) file is underlined red after adding the previously mentioned 3 lines.

I noticed there's other questions related to this but none seem to have solid answers. So I'm taking the risk that this might be a repost.

EDIT::
Here are my gradle depencies.

**Project** Gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
```

**App** Gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
}
```

EDIT 2::

Ok after migrating to androidx, I updated all my import statements to use androidx. It still kept saying merger failed with multiple errors. I had to delete the line `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` that it had previously suggested to add. Finally I was able to sync and run my app! Except now the app just starts and stops immediately. I suppose that's progress. Any ideas on this?

EDIT 3::
I finally got it to work. The last issue was a RunTimeError "Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout". This is caused because all my xml files had the line `androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout`. replaced this with the line `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`and everything is gravy now. Gradle syncs, app loads, doesn't crash and everything works as it's supposed to

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thx in advance,

Vlad

[image]

Comment: show your Gradle dependency section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your app is using `android.support` libraries while the Firebase sdk you added to your project uses `AndroidX`.

**Note**: AndroidX and android.support are not compatible.

So you have to either migrate your project to AndroidX or use a support version of Firebase.

1. Migrate code to use AndroidX

   - From `Refactor` option choose **Migrate to Androidx**.
   - Sync the project and you should be fine.
2. Use a Non-Androidx firebase.

   - Go to [Firebase release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)
   - Find the last version that is before migrating library to AndroidX 
     (For instance `Firebase messaging` 19 uses androidx and lower versions don't)

**TL;DR**

Migrate to `AndroidX` or use a lower version library of Firebase.

Comment: Tried that. Same error. Manifest merger failed with multiple errors. See Logs

Comment: Seems like you have migrated to androidX. So upgrade all dependencies to AndroidX. and leave no android.support. Also enable jetifier.

Comment: I updated the original question with where I am now. gradle sync is working but app shuts down. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, I finally got it to work. read EDIT 3. I'm accepting your solution as the answer to this post as it got me the farthest. Thank you.

Comment: Oops. Sorry for the late response. According to EDIT3, looks like the migration was not fully done and some packages where not changed.

Answer (score 0):

In your application tag add  tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
>
```

then gradle.properties add

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Comment: I already tried that, as I stated above. That still says "manifest merger failed with multiple errors"